# Minimum Value from Summed Formula in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, minimum

I am working on a crystal report. It has the following fields: item, component, warehouse, and quantity on hand. Please see detail view below:

Item    Components  Warehouse   QuantityOnHand

AZ1         153-54  100             31.00

AZ1         153-54  200             28.00

AZ1         153-54  Total 153-54    59.00

AZ1         153-84  100             31.00

AZ1         153-84  200             27.00

AZ1         153-84  Total 153-84    58.00

AZ1         153D89  100             31.00

AZ1         153D89  200             26.00

AZ1         153D89  Total 153D89    57.00

After I hide the details, I will get the following view:

Item    Components  Warehouse   QuantityOnHand

AZ1         153-54  Total 153-54    59.00

AZ1         153-84  Total 153-84    58.00

AZ1         153D89  Total 153D89    57.00

I am trying to identity the Components that have the lowest QuantityOnHand for every item. When I use the MIN function in crystal, it does not work. In this example, I would like to only show

AZ1         153D89  Total 153D89    57.00

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: AZ1 153-54 1 31.00<br/>
AZ1 153-54 2 28.00<br/>
AZ1 153-54 Total 153-54 59.00<br/>
AZ1 153-84 1 31.00<br/>
AZ1 153-84 2 27.00<br/> 
AZ1 153-84 Total 153-84 58.00<br/>
AZ1 153D89 1 31.00<br/>
AZ1 153D89 2 26.00<br/>
AZ1 153D89 Total 153D89 57.00<br/>

Answer (score 0):

Store the summary values into array and then apply min condition on array.

If min of array is equal to any value then dont supress else supress. Apply this condition on group footer

Try this:

Create a formula `@Store`

`Shared StringVar Array store;

store:=store+ToText(QuantityOnHand);`

Place above formula after QuantityOnHand

Now create a supress formula for th section that you want to hide as

`EvaluateAfter({@Store});
Shared StringVar array store;

if QuantityOnHand =Min(Store)
Then false
Else true`

Comment: How do I store the values in an array?